# Bootstrap 4 Popover Menu Showing bullet which setted as none by css

Tags: menu, popover

I'm trying to popup menu with Bootstrap 4 popover for category list.

My code below

```
 <a tabindex="0" class="nav-link catdropdown" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">Kategoriler</a>

              <ul class="no-bullet" id="categoryPopOverMenu">
                 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{$category['category_name']}} @if ($settings['show_category_movie_count'] === 1) ({{$category['movies_count']}}) @endif</a>
                         @endforeach
                 </li>
              </ul>
```

And JS code below

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                           trigger: 'focus',
                            html:true,
                            content : function() {
                                return $('#categoryPopOverMenu').html();

                            }                       
                             });
```

Please Look at below image and you can see at the left side of image my list has no bullets. Also you can see at right side of picture, a black bullet is appearing when i show my list in a popover

https://i.hizliresim.com/az01LB.png

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: Your li tag adds the bullet

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. Below code working good

```
<a tabindex="0" class="nav-link catdropdown" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">Kategoriler</a>
              <ul class="list-group" id="categoryPopOverMenu" style="padding:0px;display:none;width:70px;">
                         @foreach($categories as $category)
                             <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info justify-content-between" style="padding:0px">
                               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{$category['category_name']}} @if ($settings['show_category_movie_count'] === 1) <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill pull-right" style="font-size:11px; font-weight:normal">{{$category['movies_count']}}</span>@endif</a>
                             </li>
                         @endforeach
              </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Obviously your css is overriding. 
    Try adding this to your css:

    .popover-title {
        color: blue;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .popover-content {
        color: red;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
See this link this might help you.
```

Visit [Apply CSS to popover in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884750/apply-css-to-popover-in-bootstrap)

Comment: Sooo, you got that error about link only answer then...and you decided to bypass it..

Comment: Please read [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)