# How to set font size for popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Simple CSS question I have to ask as I'm not so good in CSS. I have done a popover modal function so when a user hovers over a link a modal shows like [image: this]

but as you can see the title shows very huge, how can I make the font size smaller?? I can't seem to find the CSS for that. my code is as below:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        trigger : 'hover'
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<a href="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\ChatbotController@queries', [$companyID, $entityType, $entityValue])}}" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="popover" title="{{ucwords($entityValue)}}" data-content="Default popover">{{ucwords($entityValue)}}</a>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
  /* Popover Header */
  .popover-title {
      font-size: 12px;
  }
  /* Popover Body */
  .popover-content {
      font-size: 12px;
  }
</style>
```

It's using bootstrap.

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Try to set max-width for popover

Comment: @davecar21 3.x?

Comment: but i want to set the font size @Sharvan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply CSS to popover in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884750/apply-css-to-popover-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 3):

Using font-size property for popover's header and body should help.

```
    /* Popover Header */
    .popover-title {
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    /* Popover Body */
    .popover-content {
        font-size: 10px;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: hi, this works for the .popover-content but its not working for the .popover-title

Answer (score 1):

No idea which version I've got but in my case it was:

```
    .popover-header {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .popover-body {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its worth noting that strangeness in font size within a popover may have to do with the container it is sitting in. Before you try to change any CSS, try to set the container via
`data-container="body"`. You can use any other container, and it will inherit the font information for that container.

By default, it will inherit whatever container it is created in.

For instance:

```
body {
    font-size: 12pt;
}

ul {
    font-size: 72pt;
}

<ul>
    <li data-toggle="popover" data-content="foobar">test</li>
</ul>
```

Is going to result in huge font size for the popover as well. However, you can do:

```
body {
    font-size: 12pt;
}

ul {
    font-size: 72pt;
}

<ul>
    <li data-toggle="popover" data-content="foobar" data-container="body">test</li>
</ul>
```

And the font size of the popover will be 12pt.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using v4.x try this css setting

```
    .popover {
      border: 1px dotted #ccc !important;
      max-width: 600px !important;
    }
    
    .popover-body{
      color: black !important;
      font-size: 12px !important;
      max-width: 600px !important;
        
    }
```